# iPhone: Block third party appliacition installation

Tags: iphone

I want to block the third party application installation in iPhone programmatically.

Want to make a controlling application that controls the installation on iPhone. Like as some father didn't want to allow his children to install any unnecessary app.

Is it possible to do that? If possible then how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unspecific about what you want to do. Why do it programmatically? For what reason? You want to install an app which blocks installation of other apps? I don't get it.

Comment: No. You cann't access to another app.

Comment: "third party application"...?? u work for apple?

Comment: Actually i want to make a controlling application that controls the installation on iPhone. Like as some father didn't want to allow his children to install app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want a sort of children protection thing. The answer is no - you cannot have an app that blocks the installation of other apps. Perhaps with jailbraking, but definitely not with standard iOS API.